# How do I find the shape of Tiled's circles or ellipses in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I created a level in the 'Tiled Map Editor' and loaded it into my libGDX game.
I can easily transform almost all objects into Box2D objects (although this problem is not Box2D specific), but I have trouble with ellipses.

Tiled seems to only create ellipse objects, without a special case for circles. I'd be happy with just circles if they existed in Tiled.

However, even the EllipseMapObject I load in libGDX only has an `x,y` position. I don't see any information about area or vertices. Did I miss something? How can I create circle or ellipse objects in Tiled and load them into libGDX with right dimensions?

---

Tiled version 0.10.1, libGDX version 1.4.1

Comment: Are you using some specific Tiled map loader in libgdx, or your own file parser?

Comment: The TMX is loaded via the build-in parser of libGDX

Comment: Tiled's file format (`.tmx`) [includes](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format#ellipse) `width` and `height` fields for ellipses since v0.9.0, which carry over to within your [`EllipseMapObject`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/objects/EllipseMapObject.java). Are you sure you're looking in the right place, calling `EllipseMapObject.getEllipse()` and checking width and height on *that*?

Comment: I think you are right @Anko, the values are there. Tiled adds objects by default with size 0. And I got confused, since this is (of course) irrelevant for polylines and polygons. So setting a proper size in tiled also shows these values in the EllipseMapObject.

Comment: OK, good. You could add an answer to summarise the situation for later visitors with the same misunderstanding, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Tiled Map Editor' sets the size (width and height) of map objects by default to 0.

For most objects this is not relevant (polylines, rectangles and triangles which are handled as polygon objects) since the vertices are important. 
But for circles and ellipses I had to set a real value of course.